# Can't understand process of page address extension

Tags: operating-system

I tried to figure out how page address extension work and read some reference in wikipedia, the picture in the end is classic structure for PAE. But I still can't figure out why this can work.

Following is my question

1. What is the size of Dir.pointer entry? 32bits?
2. Can anyone explain detail about the fact `PAE map 32 bits virtual address to 36 bits physical address`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Q1): Each *Dir.Pointer* entry is 64 bits, and these entries roughly share the same layout as the *Page Directory* entry and *Page Table* entry.  Roughly, because although the layout it shared, the interpretation of the protection and memory type bits is quite different.

In the classic 32bit + PAE, the cr3 register contains the physical address of the first *Dir.Pointer* entry in bits 31..5.  Bits 4..0 are ignored but probably should be zero.  The set of 4 *Dir.Pointers* must be 32byte aligned.  This Dir.Pointer table must be in the lower 4G of address space due to the limited size of this register.

Inside the P(DP|PD|PT) entry, this bits are laid out something like this:

```
63 -- no execute ( this page cannot execute )
62..M -- must be zero (later ignored).
(M-1)..12 -- upper M-12 bits of physical address
11..0 -- protection, size and type bits.
```

M is lg(MAX_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS) which is can be a runtime determined value.

(Q2): So, when the processor locates the (4k) page table entry corresponding to a virtual addres V, it emits:

```
 (v & 0xfff) | ((PTE (M-1)..12) << 12)
```

as the physical address.
If it noticed that the PD entry had specified a large page, it would emit:

```
 (v & 0xfffff) | ((PDE (-1)..20) << 20)
```

as the physical address.

It doesn’t matter than there are more physical bits than virtual bits in an address. A given process (address space) can only reference 4G of memory/device addresses. Several processes may be simultaneously active, each with 4G of non or partially overlapped mappings.   Thus the system supports 64G of ram, but each process may only be able to see 4G.